# Hide navbar when scrolling, but do it so that it's not animated but naturally 'scrolled away'

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, navbar, nav

so hiding the navbar when scrolling simply by adding a class with "top: -50px" for example is easy. However, it doesn't feel very natural. It would be so much nicer, if the navbar would be hiding through actual scrolling, so that the speed of the scrolling always fits. Instead of animating it away, I want to scroll the navbar away and back onscreen (instantly away and after a certain amount of pixels of scrolling up back onscreen again).

How would you approach this?

By the way, I don't really want to use any JQuery for this, I'm using Vue.

Comment: Do you only want to hide the navbar once you have scrolled past a certain point? Could you put a simple JSfiddle together for this? I have an idea but would want to play with it.

Comment: @phil: no, I want the navbar to go away 1px per 1px scrolled. naturally scrolled away.

Comment: I understand that. What I don't understand is how this is different from just placing the navbar relative to the top of the document, just like any other content.

Comment: @Phil Because I want the navbar to be fixed at the top once you scroll up a certain distance. But I don't want the transition from fixed to absolute and back to be animated, I want it to be naturally scrolled.

Comment: I think I know what you mean. Check my answer and see if it is close to what you are asking.

Comment: Please check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47721404/6399812

Answer (score 3):

I hope I didn't get things wrong but if you want the bar to hide when you scroll, why not just `position: absolute` it and leave the normal scrolling make it disappear ? that might sound trivial but if you want a natural disappearance, that might be it, no ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I may have explained this badly. I want the navbar to appear once I scroll up a certain amount of pixels and have position: fixed until I scroll down again. I think the way it might work is to change to position: absolute and give it a top value of whatever the current scroll distance is.

Comment: check my answer to see what I meant initially ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS transitions on `top` to animate it back and forth.  However you are triggering the hide when you scroll, you can add/remove classes to trigger the change.

Comment: That is precisely what I am doing at the moment, sorry if that wasn't clear. But I don't want the entire navbar to disappear when I scroll 10 pixels. I only want to hide 10px in that case.

Comment: If you put together a JSfiddle or CodePen for this, I can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Set the position of the navbar a fixed (or whatever you have currently) until a scroll event on the window passes a certain point, then make the navbar relative to the scrolling container.

See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/n97tu7nt/

The HTML

```
<div id="main-container">
  <div class="nav" id="nav" style="position:fixed; height: 100px; background-color: blue; color: white; width:100%;">
    This is the Nav Bar <span id="pos"></span>
  </div>
  <div style="position:relative; top:130px;" id="container">
    <p>
      This is some text
    </p>
  ...
```

The Javascript

```
var c = document.getElementById('nav');
var t = document.getElementById('container');
var p = document.getElementById('pos');

p.innerHTML = window.scrollY;

var last_known_scroll_position = 0;
var ticking = false;

function doSomething(scroll_pos) {

  p.innerHTML = scroll_pos;
  if (scroll_pos > 100) {
    c.style.position = 'relative';
    t.style.top = 0;
  }
}

// From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {

  last_known_scroll_position = window.scrollY;

  if (!ticking) {

    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      doSomething(last_known_scroll_position);
      ticking = false;
    });

    ticking = true;

  }

});
```

It is very hacky, but shows the principle.

Comment: not quite what I asked for, but thanks for trying :) check out my answer to see what I meant.